# Load OpenStreetMap in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, openstreetmap

How can I reload OSM in a hidden div?
I first load it, hide the div and let the div show up onclick(). I see the OSM controls but the map doesn't appear. How to fix it? I tried:

```
    $('#OpenLayers_Map_55_OpenLayers_ViewPort').updateSize();
```

Without success..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden (or display: none;) contents is not loading. Try set absolute position and left: -10000px for target div. This is like hidden but not hidden.